# Push JS Object to array overwrites existing objects

Tags: javascript

I have this JS object:

```
  baseFarm = {
    name: "Farm",
    tier: 1,
    gridPos: 32,
  }
```

and I want to push it to this array:

```
ownedLand = [];
```

This works perfectly, and if I console log this after the push I get:
[image]

Now, I want to push another another object to the same array, using that one as a base, however, I want the "gridPos" property to be different:

```
var newLand = baseFarm;
newLand.gridPos = parseInt( $('#purchaseLandPopupPlotNum').text() );
this.ownedLand.push(newLand);
```

However, after pushing this new object, the old one gets updated too:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the same object to the new variable here:

```
var newLand = baseFarm;
```

So when you modify `newLand`, you are changing `baseFarm` aswell (and the object pushed to the array). And you are pushing the same object twice to the array.

Instead, you should **clone** `baseFarm`, either with `Object.assign()`:

```
var newLand = Object.assign({}, baseFarm);
```

Or the more trendy spread operator:

```
var newLand = { ...baseFarm };
```

As an addendum, you could clone and modify the property on the same operation:

```
var newLand = Object.assign({}, baseFarm, { gridPos: parseInt( $('#purchaseLandPopupPlotNum').text() } );
```

In which case you wouldn't even need a new variable (or the `baseFarm` even, if it's always on the 0 index of the array):

```
this.ownedLand.push(Object.assign({}, this.ownedLand[0], { gridPos: parseInt( $('#purchaseLandPopupPlotNum').text() } ));
```

I'll let the spread version up to you :-)